# Known word missing in nlp.vocab

Tags: spacy

I was exploring the dictionary of spaCy's standard `en` model when I came across an inconsistency I do not understand:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
'irritably' in spacy.en.language_data.LEMMA_INDEX['adv'] # True
'irritably' in nlp.vocab # False
```

So far this is the only word I cannot find in `nlp.vocab`. Any idea, why it is not there? What is my misconception here?

Answer (score 3):

The reason could be the size of the default `en` model, default model is the smaller 50MB model `en_core_web_sm` whose data might not be that exhaustive, your typical usecase does not occure with the bigger model `en_core_web_md`

```
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
>>> u'irritably' in spacy.en.language_data.LEMMA_INDEX['adv']
True
>>> u'irritably' in nlp.vocab
True
```

I assume vocab and language_data might not be fully consistent with each other and depend on volume of training data the model has.